# How can I make text from the first line align with an image?

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment, wrapfigure

I'm writing a letter and I want to use an image as the first letter (A la olde time book Initials). See the below screenshot of what I've thrown together so far.

What I would like to do is have the text in the first line, align with the bottom of the image, so the only text in line with the image is "tefan, long has my search gone on...". In the past I've found it quite difficult to move text that is on the top line without changing the header spacing, but in this scenario that would also move the image and defeat the purpose.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{letter}

\usepackage{yfonts,color, graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\graphicspath{{Images/}}

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}[6]{l}{0pt}
  \vspace{-20pt}
    \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{Snakewborder.png}
  \vspace{-20pt}
\end{wrapfigure}

tefan, long ago...

\end{document}
```

If anyone has any recommendations please send them my way. Thanks!

[image: Snake Letter Image]

Comment: Related: the [`lettrine`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lettrine) package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want the picture in line with the first line of text. If that is the case, then you don't need the wrapfigure. `\includegraphics` all by itself will put the picture where text would start. So I commented out the `\wrapfigure` lines and erased the blank line between the image and the text.

```
\begin{document}

%\begin{wrapfigure}[1]{l}{0pt}
%  \vspace{-20pt}
    \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{Snakewborder.png}%
        %  \vspace{-20pt}
        %\end{wrapfigure}
tefan, long ago...

\end{document}
```

Is this what you're looking for?

[image]

Comment: Heh, wow I just learned about wrapfig and didn't even bother trying include because I originally wanted what I had in the first place. Thanks a ton!